# user auth Laravel 5.2

Tags: authentication, routes, laravel-5

in my project I need to protect some views.
I create a router group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function (){ 

//Spot
  Route::get('administrator/spot-new', 'SpotController@create');
  Route::post('administrator/spot-new', 'SpotController@store');
}
```

in my Spot Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

but when I try to access to spot view I can't see the login page. 
I have this error:
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Check this out, maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567068/laravel-5-2-auth-registration-page-blocked/36567538#36567538

Comment: use  ['middleware' => ['web','auth']]

Comment: in Authenticate middleware      if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 have added Middleware Groups.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups

Web middleware group is responsible for Start Session / Encrypt Cookies / Verify CSRF Token etc.. see below

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
```

> You're required to add when working with sessions and any other stuff
>   in that group.

So to solve your problem add 'web' to your middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function (){ 
  Route::get('administrator/spot-new', 'SpotController@create');
  Route::post('administrator/spot-new', 'SpotController@store');
}
```

And in your controller constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
   //$this->middleware('auth'); (No need for this one)
}
```